# Mini Pages to child tex document

Tags: lyx, minipage

I am trying to make minipages work in lyx. I have a tex(1.tex) file, which contains the body of the minipages with the float figures I have, which goes like this

```
\begin{figure} ..\begin{minipages}....\end{minipages}..... \end{figure}
```

In my otherwise normal LyX document, I have written the ERT \include{1.tex}.
This does not compile properly and spews out these errors :

Too many }s. 
\begin{document} ended by \end{figure}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I migtht be missing something, but isn't the environment called `minipage` (singular, not plural)? Otherwise we will probably need a full code example to diagnose the issue, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: Please read http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample and post a `.lyx` minimal example. Also, can you reproduce the error *without* ERT? You can include files with Insert > File > Child Document.